# Android thread in for loop

Tags: android, multithreading, for-loop

I have a for loop which includes a thread on it.The code works but the parameter is not passing to the function correctly. Can you help me?

```
for(i= 1 ;i < 30; i++) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            example_function(i);
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: `i` needs to be `final` to be visible in the anonymous `Thread` inner-class :) Other than that, what's not passing right? what's the expected outcome and what was the actual outcome/output?

Comment: in function i print i values and they are not 1 to 30. Some values comes 2 or 3 times

Comment: I'm guess `i` is a class field then and that is why it is running without being final. By the time you run your thread and it prints `i` might have been incremented multiple times and that is why you are getting duplicates.

Comment: make sure `i` is `synchronized` or `volatile` then and ... see if that improves it? good catch @GeorgeMulligan I did not consider a blatant race-condition.
@Shockelduck please attach your output so we can better see the problem please.

Comment: That won't do it either because all running threads still see same `i`. OP could have an int field on the `Thread` and pass `i` into the constructor of the Thread.

Comment: Agreed again, but perhaps a deep clone isn't very necessary (i know, we're dealing with ints here but blindfolded debugging has different impressions on different people). that's why i asked him to attach the output he's getting as well so we can get a more pinpointed idea of what's really going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `Thread` with a parameter:

```
class IntThread extends Thread {

    private int i;

    public IntThread( int i ) {
       this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        example_function( this.i );
    }
}
```

then execute it as:

```
    for(int i= 1 ;i < 30; i++) {
        new IntThread( i ).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code looks suspicious to begin with but you should really be using `Runnable`s with the Threads.

Something like this would print what you want if you add a `MyRunnable` class like below:

```
private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int i;
    public MyRunnable(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        example_function(i);
    }
}
```

and then your for loop becomes:

```
for(i= 1 ;i < 30; i++) {
    new Thread(new MyRunnable(i)).start();
}
```

The numbers can still print out of order but each will only be printed once.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a field int j to your thread and initialize it with thread.j = i before you run your thread

```
for(i= 1 ;i < 30; i++) {
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    final int j;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        example_function(j);
    }
 };
thread.j = i;
thread.start();
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but this code wouldn't compile -- `Thread` doesn't have a member named `j` -- and `final` members can't be changed anyway.